# cookie alternatives for modern web dev?

Tags: javascript, cookies, web

Are there any recommended alternatives to cookies for modern web dev? I was trying to refamiliarize myself with cookies for a current task I'm working on and came across this wikipedia article which has an "alternatives" section for cookies:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Structure

I was implementing cookies 20 years ago so I wasn't sure if a better more modern approach had emerged and superseded cookies for some use cases.

Comment: You could look into local/session storage on modern browsers

Comment: localStorage, sessionStorage

Comment: Cookies are a tool. There are many other tools available. First you have to describe what problems you have before anyone can suggest a better tool to solve the problem.

Comment: You should be more specific about what your task is. As I pointed out, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are not necessarily a replacement in all cases.

Comment: the specific use case is that there will be a series of notifications displayed in the page header. each of these notifications will have an id. if the user clicks the close button to close a notification then js should save the notification id to persist that the user has closed that particular notification. this will prevent the js from redisplaying a notification that the user has already read and dismissed.  would local storage be the modern implementation approach in this scenario?

Comment: I took a look at my "Local Storage" in chrome dev tools Resources. It has several entries from Google. Therefore, I'm assuming that Google has moved from cookies and now uses "Local Storage" exclusively if the current browser supports it.  Does this seem like a correct assumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your needs. `localStorage` has replaced sessions and cookies for many things on the front end, like storing user data, tokens etc.

Nowadays I use `localStorage` for most things that I used to use Cookies for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `localStorage` Or `sessionStorage` depending on your usecase

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: This is assuming that the task does not involve fetching server resources, as `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are not sent with HTTP requests like cookies are.

Comment: You can always serialize the data stored and send with the request. There would be an overhead if you don't opt for cookies.

Comment: You can't serialize and send the data with non-xhr requests though, and that's usually how cookies are used anyway.

Comment: Are cookies good enough nowadays though? Or should one really make the switch?